# Always get port number with @Url.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I used `@Url.Action("Scan", "System", null, "http", Request.Url.Host)` to create the URL for a link.

When I run this out of Visual Studio, I get a URL like http://localhost:61962/System/Scan

The server I need to deploy this website to includes a port number (ie port 10000) which appears in the URL. When this same @Url.Action code runs on the server, it gives me a URL http://127.0.0.1/System/Scan This doesn't work because it doesn't include the port and appears to be trying to use port 80 instead of 10000.

I tried to do this code to include the port: `@Url.Action("Scan", "System", null, "http", Request.Url.Host + ":" + Request.Url.Port)`

The problem is while this works on the server, when I run out of Visual Studio, I end up with a URL like this: http://localhost:61962:61962/System/Scan (ie port number is listed twice).

Any thoughts on how I can make this work for both scenarios? Like forcing @Url.Action to always include the port?

Comment: Is this a link external to your application? E.g. another server or different port?

Comment: Typically, hostname and port are not provided by `Url.Action`. I usually see the links formatted as absolute paths against the site root, ex: `/Area/Controller/Action`. Is there any reason you must specify the hostname?

Comment: Why you specify the host instead of simple `@Url.Action("Scan", "System")`?

Comment: @Kris Have you found a solution? I have exactly the same problem

Comment: Honestly this was 2 1/2 years ago that I posted this and don't really remember. I don't think I did, but I can't even find this code anymore. Sorry.